# Show that $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ dx$ exists. (trouble understanding solutions)

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

The question comes from Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 14 problem 28(e).
Preliminary steps were made to split the integral into the form

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ dx = 2 \cdot \lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ dx
$$

However, I do not quite understand the concluding statement made in the solutions, which states that:

*... by part(a), $\lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} \ dx$ exists. It can be shown that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $ for $-1 < x < 0$, then it follows that $\lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ dx$ exists as well.*

---

In this case clearly $\lim_{x \to -1^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -1^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \infty$. I have two questions with regards to this:

1. How does it follow that because $\lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} \ dx$ exists, then $\lim_{\epsilon \to -1^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ dx$ exists as well?
2. Most importantly, is this a generalizable concept? (i.e. if the limits of two functions $f, g \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow a$,  and $f > g$ in some interval, then if $\lim_{x \to a} \int_{b}^{x} f$ exists, $\lim_{x \to a}\int_{b}^{x} g$ exists as well.)

Answer (score 1):

This is because, if you denote $\:F(x)=\int_b^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$, $\:G(x)=\int_b^x g(t)\,\mathrm dt$, $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are increasing functions of $x$ when $x$ is close to $a$, and
$$G(x) \le F(x)\le \int_b^a\!\!f(t)\,\mathrm dt,$$
i.e. $G(x)$ is increasing and bounded.

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand. Isn't the bounds between the actual functions themselves, not their definite integrals?

Comment: The bound for $F(x)$ is its limit which is the improper integral. Isn't it clear? I just applied the *monotone convergence theorem* for $G(x)$.

Comment: Yes, but I was originally confused because I could not see how the inequality presented in the original question, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} >\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ leads to the conclusion for integrals. Also, I apologize as I am unfamiliar with the aforementioned monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Didn't you see it in high school (whatever name it was given)?

Comment: No, I don't recall any theorem with a similar name. Perhaps I did learn it in some form, but it is okay. Thank you, I appreciate the effort.

Comment: It simply says that an increasing sequence with an upper bound  or a decreasing sequence with a lower bound converge, and it can be extended to functions of a real variable.